# Show USDC price of NFT in phantom wallet using Metaplex JS SDK Candy Machine V3

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program, candy-machine-v3

I built a V3 candy machine using metaplex sdk and have my collection payment in USDC instead of Sol. The price of the NFT doesn’t appear in phantom wallet during mint approval.

Is there something I can do to correct that or is that an issue on phantom’s end?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the SPL-token mints I've seen on Candy Machine v3, I believe that Phantom has parsed the transaction data to show SPL Token Mint fees to users.

Have you confirmed the Candy Machine works and is correctly configured? Is it charging the expected amount of USDC?

Do you have several groups or a number of other Candy Guards set? If #1 is true, I suspect maybe there are some edge cases around how combined guards or groups are/are not parsed in the wallet. But not sure.